# Use webpack to inject custom bootstrap using a Link tag

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

I want to customize bootstrap to my needs, and I'm trying to use webpack to inject my CSS as a link tag.

I've installed:

- webpack
- mini-css-extract-plugin
- sass
- node-sass
- sass-loader
- css-loader

And this is what I have tried so far:

```js
// I want to take the content of custom-bootstrap, and inject it as a link tag.
{
  include: resolve('src/scss/custom-bootstrap.scss'),
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Injects the styles into a link tag.
    //"style-loader", // 3. Injects styles into the DOM.
    "css-loader", // 2. Turns css into js.
    "sass-loader", // 1. Turns sass into css.
  ]
}
```

The contents of `custom-bootstrap.scss` looks like this:

```css
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I also have another webpack rule (`/\.(sc|c)ss$/i`) very similar to the one above with is to handle every other style in the app. It looks like this:

```js
{
  test: /\.(sc|c)ss$/i,
  exclude: resolve('src/scss/custom-bootstrap.scss'),
  use: [
    // MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Injects the styles into a link tag.
    "style-loader", // 3. Injects styles into the DOM.
    "css-loader", // 2. Turns css into js.
    "sass-loader", // 1. Turns sass into css.
  ]
}
```

When I run webpack I get the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected "{".
  ╷
2 │       import API from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";.
```

Anyone knows how to solve this? I also tried to use a a path to the `node_modules` instead of using the `~` syntax in the scss file, but without luck. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you check your `custom-bootstrap.scss` (or another) file for a missing `"{"`?

Comment: Yep! @ITgoldman :)

Comment: I would try to compile the sass files in VS Code using one of many extensions, just to see if it compiles and where is the error if any.

Comment: Thank you @ITgoldman I will give it a try in order to rule out an error. However, I don't think that's it because SCSS file imports everything from bootstrap (the package). Will also try to create a codesandbox to replicate. :)